# how can I get handle errors from UseInterceptors Decorator

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs, multer

I make a controller that controller receives image files. but I want to filter image extension (jpg/png/gif) then I make an image filter function that function works correctly but when the function throw error. Getting error response `500 internal server error` but terminal shows the actual error of the image `Only image files are allowed!`

I can't accept the error from the callback function to return response this error.
any solution here to callback returns the error

```
//this is Image Filter Function
export const imageFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
  return callback(new Error('Only image files are allowed!'), false);
}
  callback(null, true);
};
```

> Controller file code

```
@Post('/profile-image')
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('img', 1, { fileFilter: imageFileFilter }))
async profile(
  @UploadedFile() file,
): Promise<string> {
  return await this.prfile.upload(file);
}
```

Comment: What if you change `Error` to `BadRequestException`? Does it still come back as 500 or is it now 400?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Thank you brother when I add `BadRequestException` its work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Nest's default [Exception Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) treats any error that is not an instance of `HttpException` (an error class from Nest) as an `Internal Server Error` and just sends back a 500. To combat this, you can either use an `HttpException` subclass (like `BadRequestException`) or you can create your own exception filter that will read the error and send the appropriate response. Both approaches are fine, but the `HttpException` approach is more straightforward

Answer (score 0):

when add `BadRequestException` after work correclty

```
//this is Image Filter Function
 export const imageFileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
 if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
   return callback(
   new BadRequestException('Only image files are allowed!'),
   false,
 );
 }
   callback(null, true);
 };
```